# Delete DLL after closing c# application

Tags: c#, dispose

I Have a c# application that include various esternal DLL. When the application start, dlls are exctracted in the .exe folder to grant the correct execution.
here the code:

```
var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

string folderName = string.Format("{0}.Resources.DLLs", executingAssembly.GetName().Name);
var list = executingAssembly
.GetManifestResourceNames()
.ToArray();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(item.Replace("myapp.DLLs.", ""), 
    ReadAllBytes(executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(item)));
}
```

when i close the form, i want to delete those files with this code, associated to the form closing event:

```
private void CleanFiles(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string folderName = string.Format("{0}.Resources.DLLs", executingAssembly.GetName().Name);
    string folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    var list = executingAssembly
    .GetManifestResourceNames()
    .ToArray();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {

        File.Delete(folder + @"\" + item.Replace("myapp.DLLs.", ""));
    }
}
```

If I open and then close the form, it works perfectly. But, if I open the form, do some operations, it throw an exception during the closing operations because access to dlls is denied.
How can I release all dlls/resources?

Comment: Instead of deleting the DLLs from within the process using them, I'd start another process (being NOT child of) whose work is just to delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that if you copy these DLLs, you load and use them afterwards.

There's a slight issue with dynamically loading DLLs, being that you can't just unload them. Once loaded into your application domain, they're here to stay.

The solution is thus to simply create a new application domain, load the DLL inside of it, and when you're done, unload this new application domain.

Something like:

```
var dynamicDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("YourDomainName");
var dynamicallyLoadedAssembly = dynamicDomain.Load("YourAssembly");

// do stuff with your dynamically loaded assembly

AppDomain.Unload(dynamicDomain);
```

For more information on the topic: [MSDN "How to: Load and unload assemblies"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/load-unload).

Answer (score -4):

You can (and should) implement exception handling around the parts where you manipulate files on the system:

```cs
try
{
  // Manipulate your files here.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Handle exceptions here. you can also delete the dlls here if you wish.
  // Remember to check in CleanFiles if the files are already deleted.
}
finally
{
  // You could also get rid of the files here.
  // Finally-block is executed regardless if an exception was thrown or not.
}
```

Usefull links: [Microsoft: Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/exception-handling), [Microsoft: Best Ractices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions)

Comment: While not wrong, it does not actually answer the question asked.

Comment: This catches the exception, but won't solve the problem.

Comment: I dont see where it doesn't solve the problem? He cant delete the files when an exception is thrown. Catch the exception, delete the files, problem solved. Or did I understand something wrong? English is not my native language, so sorry if I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Well no :) if he tries to delete the file in the catch (or finally) block, he's just going to get the same exception again.

Comment: If the file is in use, and you get an error saying "I cannot delete the file because the file is in use," then ignoring the error and trying again will only yield the same result... that error.

Comment: Yeah, ok, I see where I went wrong, sorry! Thanks for the explanation.